# Can you create a button with editable content using HTML and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button that is editable only when a separate "Edit Button Above" is clicked, then reverts back to a normal button after clicking on the same "Edit Button". What is a good way to approach this?

My code is as follows:

```
<button>Button Text Could Be Editable</button><br />
<button>Edit Button Above</button>
```

If this can't be done or not recommended, am flexible to "fake buttons" (i.e. fake a button with a div, etc. Am looking for an elegant solution to this problem.)

Comment: What do you mean by edit? Like change the text? If that's what you mean, you definitely can do that, and that's exactly what you'd use javascript for :)

Comment: Yes, change the text, but for the user to change it. I want them to be able to "customize" the button of the text. This customization would be saved to a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `data-*` attribute at last `<button>` element, for example `data-edit="0"`, at `click` on last `<button>` set `data-edit` to `"1"` and evaluate the result as a number cast to `Boolean` value, `true` or `false`.

Set result of `data-edit` value cast to `Boolean` as value for `this.previousElementSibling.previousElement.sibling.contextEditable`.

```html
<button>Button Text Could Be Editable</button><br />
<button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.contentEditable = !!(+(this.dataset.edit = this.dataset.edit == 0 ? 1 : 0))" data-edit="0">Edit Button Above</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just toggling within the text in a button this sample below would work. 
I have passed the `id` of the button element to the function triggered in the `onclick`. Then I have used `firstchild` in the `getElementById` where firstChild returns the first child node as an element node, a text node or a comment node.

This is just to toggle text of the button element, to actually do a function when clicking the button simply call multiple functions with that `onClick` just like this `onClick="mainFunction(); toggleText(this.id);"`

I'm simply adding and `contenteditable` attribute with value set to true when its edit true and removing the atttribute when its false.

```js
    function toggleText(button_id)  {
       var text = document.getElementById(button_id).firstChild;
       text.data = text.data == "Save Edit" ? "Edit Button Above" : "Save Edit";
       this.toggleEdit(text.data);
    }
    
    function toggleEdit (data) {
    if(data === "Edit Button Above") {
 document.getElementById("secondButton").removeAttribute("contenteditable");
    } else {
     $(document.getElementById("secondButton")).attr("contenteditable", true);
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="secondButton" contenteditable=false>Button Text Could Be Editable </button>
    <br/>
    <button id="myButton" onClick=" toggleText(this.id);">Edit Button Above</button>
```

Comment: *"`// no ';' here`"* - No kidding. Was somebody trying to put one there? The OP didn't...

Comment: @nnnnnn That's when you try to copy code from other similar stackoverflow questions, updated the answer

Comment: This doesn't make the button text editable, it simply changes it. OP wants to allow the user to specify the text.

Comment: @nnnnnn is correct, the challenge I have is being able to edit the button of the tex

Comment: @nnnnnn  My bad misunderstood the question hope now it make sense